# C# - Can't pass Out with an Override method

Tags: c#, overriding, out

I have a method very similar to the example below, and it won't let me `out` the `outItem`.

```
    public override bool myMethod(string item, out string outItem)
    {
        outItem = "";
        return true;
    }
```

It keeps giving the the following error:

> "no suitable method found to override"

If I remove the `override`, the error goes away. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `"I have a method very similar to.."`, To override, method signature has to be an exact match, not *similar*.

Comment: Does the superclass of the class containing this method also have this exact method (name & signature must match)? If not, it is not an override.

Comment: Remove the override? What's it overriding?

Comment: @Habib Technically the overriding type can have different names for the parameters, and that is a part of the signature, so it doesn't need to be an *exact* match.  I don't think anything else can vary though.

Comment: @Servy, I am not sure if that would be part of signature, I believe signature is just specific to `type` and not parameter names.

Comment: @Habib That's not true as of C# 4.0 when named parameters were added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that the method in the base class doesn't mark that parameter as `out`.  You need to conform to the base class's signature.  If you can change the base class to mark the method as `out`, then you can mark it as such on the derived type as well.  If you can't, then you won't be able to override the method, you'll have to create a new method instead.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the base class signature of myMethod doesn't use `out` for the second parameter.  You can't just add that in because it changes the method signature.  If you have control of the base class you can add it, but if not you'll need to remove the override.

Comment: Note that if you just remove the override, this method will be *different than* the one in the base class, meaning if you have something like `MyBase b = new MyConcrete(); bool result = b.myMethod("hello", out outItem);` it will not compile as the new method is not defined in the base class.

Comment: @EricJ. Yes, I realize that.  But if he can't change the base class his options are pretty limited and he won't be able to do what he wants.

Comment: The note is more for him, to make sure he's aware of the implication of this being a new method.